# Adding a variable into a function-node with a curl request

Tags: curl, node-red

could you help me with following function? I am trying to add the following variable temp to my curl request but it is not working. Thanks

```
var temp = global.targettemp;
msg.headers = {};
msg.headers={'Authorization': 'user:pass' 
msg.payload = {};
msg.payload={'targetTemperature': 'temp'};

return msg
```

Comment: You can not apply formatting in a code block, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62854296/edit) the question to remove the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
var temp = global.get('targettemp');
msg.headers={authorization: 'user:pass' };

msg.payload={targetTemperature: temp};

return msg
```

Please note the correct way to make use of context variables is to use the get/set method to ensure that the values are stored in which ever context storage plugin is in use.

Comment: @Christoph https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers